# Render Components in React by for loop

Tags: reactjs

i want to make vor example x=3, x=3, also 9 buttons, i dont know why it dont work when i put it in my for loop. with a render button method with "render() buttons. when i do a conole.log it renders 9 times, i guess its something with props or state but i dont know how i can fix it

```
import React,{ Component } from "react";
import Buttons from "./Buttons";

class Square extends Component{
    state={
        x:"",
        y:"",
        maze:"",
    }






       addButtons(){
           var s=this.state.x*this.state.y

           for(var i=0;i<s;i++){

                console.log("test")


            }



       }



    render(){
        const x= this.state.x
        const y= this.state.y
        const all= x*y
        return(
            //speichern von x und y in state
            <div id="total">


            <div id="xvalue">
                x
                <input onChange={event=>this.setState({x: event.target.value})}></input>
            </div>

            <div id="yvalue">
                y
                <input onChange={event=>this.setState({y: event.target.value})}></input>

            </div>

            <div id="button press">


                <button onClick={this.addButtons()}> create button </button>


            </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Square;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are probably looking for something like this. basically have a state that keeps track of whether to render the button or not. once that flag is turned on, you can render your x*y num of buttons in render

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Buttons from "./Buttons";

class Square extends Component {
  state = {
    x: "",
    y: "",
    maze: "",
    renderButtons: false
  };

  addButtons() {
    this.setState({ renderButtons: true });
  }

  render() {
    const x = this.state.x;
    const y = this.state.y;
    const all = x * y;
    return (
      //speichern von x und y in state
      <div id="total">
        <div id="xvalue">
          x
          <input
            onChange={event => this.setState({ x: event.target.value })}
          ></input>
        </div>

        <div id="yvalue">
          y
          <input
            onChange={event => this.setState({ y: event.target.value })}
          ></input>
        </div>

        <div id="button press">
          <button onClick={this.addButtons()}> create button </button>
          // move this line to where you want these buttons to appear
          {this.state.renderButtons && Array(this.state.x * this.state.y)
            .fill(0)
            .map(b => (
              <button></button>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Square;
```